# Need A Value of id of url inside a box

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

i am a newbie having difficulty in this. i did not getting a value of ID In A box for Update Inside A Box.

**update code**

```
    <?php

require_once (__DIR__ . '/../../config.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/local/message/classes/form/edit.php');



global $DB;
$PAGE->set_url(new moodle_url('/local/message/update.php'));
$PAGE->set_context(\context_system::instance());
$PAGE->set_title('Edit');
//here display form

$mform=new edit();
$table='local_message';
$id=required_param('id', PARAM_INT);
$info=$DB->get_records($table,array('id' => $id));


if ($mform->is_cancelled()) {
    print_r("1");
    redirect($CFG->wwwroot.'/local/message/manage.php', 'You Cancelled The Form');
} else if ($fromform = $mform->get_data()) {
    print_r("2");
    $record = new stdClass();
    $record->id=$id;
    $record->messagetext = $fromform->messagetext;
    $record->messagetype = $fromform->messagetype;
    $DB->update_record($table, $record);
    redirect($CFG->wwwroot . '/local/message/manage.php', 'you created a message with a title ' . $fromform->messagetext);
}
echo $OUTPUT->header();
$mform->display();

echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

**Form/moodle/Code**

```
<?php
require_once("$CFG->libdir/formslib.php");

class edit extends moodleform {
    public function definition() {
        global $CFG;
        $mform = $this->_form; // Don't forget the underscore!

        $mform->addElement('text', 'id');
        $mform->setType('id', PARAM_INT);
        $mform->addElement('text', 'messagetext', get_string('message_text', 'local_message')); // Add elements to your form
        $mform->setType('messagetext', PARAM_NOTAGS);                   //Set type of element
        $mform->setDefault('messagetext', get_string('enter_message', 'local_message'));        //Default value

        $choices = array();
        $choices['0'] = \core\output\notification::NOTIFY_WARNING;
        $choices['1'] = \core\output\notification::NOTIFY_SUCCESS;
        $choices['2'] = \core\output\notification::NOTIFY_ERROR;
        $[enter image description here][1]choices['3'] = \core\output\notification::NOTIFY_INFO;
        $mform->addElement('select', 'messagetype', get_string('message_type', 'local_message'), $choices);
        $mform->setDefault('messagetype', '3');

        $this->add_action_buttons();
    }
    //Custom validation should be added here
    function validation($data, $files) {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `id` to the form before displaying the form

```
$mform->set_data($info);
$mform->display();
```

Also, you should use the single `get_record` function not the multiple `get_records` function

```
$info = $DB->get_record($table, array('id' => $id));
```

Also, you might want to use the `hidden` element for the `id`

```
$mform->addElement('hidden', 'id');
```